# Skip first optional parameter and pass in second to backbone model.save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Backbone's [model.save()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) method has the following signature:

`model.save([attributes], [options])`

I want to call it, but I don't want to pass in any attributes, only options. I need it this way because I set the attributes before saving using `model.set(attributes)`.

How can I pass in just one object to `model.save()` but indicate that it is the options object and not the attributes object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is explicit on this so we have to look at [the source](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L353):

```
save: function(key, val, options) {
  var attrs, current, done;

  // Handle both `"key", value` and `{key: value}` -style arguments.
  if (key == null || _.isObject(key)) {
    attrs = key;
    options = val;
  } else if (key != null) {
    (attrs = {})[key] = val;
  }
```

And below that you'll see various `if (attrs ...)` checks. So if you say

```
m.save(null, options)
```

you'll save the model as-is and you'll be able to set your `options`. Furthermore, if you say this:

```
m.save(some_attrs, options);
```

then that is (more or less) the same as:

```
m.set(some_attrs);
m.save(null, options);
```

Comment: Gotcha. Should have peeked into the source. The docs are a bit of a let down sometimes. Thanks!

Comment: @xbonez: The docs skip some important details but on the upside, the source is very readable.